# MySQL, PHP, extracting and formatting multiple values from on database field

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am a beginner and got stuck. Any help will be very much appreciated.

I have a text field in the database, the values in the field are as follow, i.e.: "John: 20; Dan: 30; Greg: 80; Sam: 66; Coco: 97;" this all in one field.

The result that I would like to get is as follows:
John is 20 years old
Dan is 30 years old
Greg is 80 years old

Thank you

Comment: Please provide example DB structure. Also please clarify records, are semi-colons separating rows in your example or is that all one row?

Comment: @chris85 he wrote "this all in one field", so I assume, it's all in one field ;o). Vladimir: want the solution to be all mysql, php or does it matter anyway?

Comment: @Jakumi It'd be better if reproducible code was provided. As is we are guessing here.

Comment: @chris85 I assume there is no code yet.

Comment: Store your data in two columns (`name`, `age`). That would make your live easier. Your next question could be "How do I sort the data by age?" - Which would be easy to answer with two columns.

Answer (score 2):

Please run below code

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, ':', ' is ')
```

and this replaces ':' character with ' is'

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, ';', 'years old')
```

and this replaces ';', 'years old'

At the end of this query

```
John: 20; Dan: 30; Greg: 80; Sam: 66; Coco: 97;
```

above string will be below string

```
John is 20 years old Dan is 30 years old Greg is 80 years old  Sam is 66 years old Coco is 97 years old
```

Comment: REPLACE() also works with SELECT, So without updating the column value it is possible to SELECT from the text field as per the output required.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name + ' is ' + age + ' years old' 
FROM your_table_name
```

Here name is the column name of people(John, Dan, Grek) and age is the column name of ages (20, 30, 80)